# что возвращает decltype и как он работает?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, типы, операторы

Всем здравствуйте. Я начал недавно изучать c++ и столкнулся с оператором decltype. Насколько я знаю, операторы как и функции возвращают определенное значение, но ознакомившись с документацией на сайте microsoft (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/decltype-cpp?view=msvc-160) я увидел следующую строчку "decltype Описатель типа возвращает тип указанного выражения.". Насколько мне известно тип, в качестве возвращаемого значения, не может быть возвращен, но тогда как это происходит? Заранее спасибо, надеюсь вы поможете.

Comment: decltype - спецификатор, а не оператор.

Comment: В можно про это по подробнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, например

```
int a;

...
```

Хочу объявить переменную того же типа, что и `a`...

```
decltype(a) b;
```

Грубо - но для понимания сойдет - `decltype(a)` заменяется типом, с которым была объявлена `a` - **decl**ared **type**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, извините за настойчивость, но мне хотелось бы кое-что уточнить, а конкретно меня смущает данная фраза "decltype Описатель типа возвращает тип указанного выражения." Каким образом можно возвращать тип? Или это просто некая условность?

Comment: @n1kzzz, если посмотреть англ. версию документации по приведённой в вашем вопросе ссылке, то там будет такая фраза: "The decltype type specifier **yields** the type of a specified expression". Это скорее не "возвращает", а что-то вроде "даёт/производит/вырабатывает". В общем, корявый перевод :)

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

`decltype` и не имеет никакого возвращаемого значения, так как это не функция, а часть спецификатора типа. По сути это конструкция, родственная `*` (делает из типа слева указатель или `&&` (делает из типа слева rvalue ссылку). В отличие от них, `delctype` делает тот тип, который имеет выражение в круглых скобках. При этом выражение в круглых скобках не является выполняемым (unevaluated context).